# Android 7.0 shows blank screen when trying to open url in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat

Im facing one issue in Android 7.0 (moto g4) where im trying to load one url in the webview but it shows a blank white screen.It is working with Android M and below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private String webviewURL="http://henmilholidayhomesgoa.com/player2/documentation/EULA.html";


    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setTextZoom(60);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl(webviewURL);

    }

}
```

**NOTE:- The url mentioned in the code is not the actual url which unfortunately i cant share :(.Its an url with https. But the given url in the post actually working ,Please let me know if any other input are needed.Thanks in advance**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what type of url you are opening, i mean to say any document or a website or a pdf or any other media type ?

Comment: If the above url works fine then so should your desired url.
The url in your post has http try entering some other url with https
Say: "https://www.google.com"

Comment: You are going to need to find some URL that can reproduce the problem that you *can* put in your question.

Comment: Sure i will update it when i find one @CommonsWare

Comment: I saved the html page to my asset folder and tried it is working(in android 7.0) but it shows some ASCII characters in it. So i tried to retrieve the url content programmatically and   used  webview.loadData(response, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null); that is also working(in android 7.0). Any comments on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code:

In this there is a webview and a progress bar.In this code url will be loaded as soon as progress bar disappears and if there is any link within the url it will open it as well in the webview.

Below is the **java** code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ShowWebView extends Activity {

    //private Button button;
    private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

        //Get webview 
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        startWebView("http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/login.html");

    }

    private void startWebView(String url) {

        //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        //When opening a url or click on link

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }); 

         // Javascript inabled on webview  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        // Other webview options
        /*
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        */

        /*
         String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
         webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
         */

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }

    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Now below is the respective **xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>       
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check this code in android 7.0. Hope it helps you out !

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your same code and run the application on nougat Nexus 9 .
It take time to load the URL wait for 5 minutes otherwise check with other device of Nougat.

```
public class WebviewMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView wv;
private String webviewURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425766/android-7-0-shows-blank-screen-when-trying-to-open-url-in-webview";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_main);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setTextZoom(60);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(webviewURL);
}}
```

[image: See this image from Nexus 9]

Hope this help.Happy coding.Please let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Asus Nexus 7. Webview version was 56 while Chrome browser app had lower version. After I updated Google Chrome app webview started working fine.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have use Google pixel. i have face same problem and as per your comment i have update my crome app but still same issue face. Please reply me any other solution. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loadDataWithBaseURL instead of loadData and try, I was facing similar issues on some devices.